# Merging one-by-many CSV files in Python

Tags: python, csv, import-from-csv

I have the output of a series of stochastic simulations in the form of a .csv file that look something like this:

```
Run,ID,Var
1,1,7
1,2,9
1,3,4
2,1,3
2,2,4
2,3,8
```

etc.

Along with that, I have another data file, also a .csv, formatted like so:

```
ID, Var2, Var3
1,0.89,0.10
2,0.45,0.98
3,0.27,0.05
4,0.98,0.24
```

**Note**: There are some values in the data file that *do not* appear in the simulation file. I'd like these to be ignored.

What I'd like to do is write a script that takes each value `ID` from the first .csv file, and finds Var2 and Var3 and puts it together, to end up with something like:

```
Run, ID, Var, Var2, Var3
1,1,7,0.89,0.10
1,2,9,0.45,0.98
1,3,4,0.27,0.05
2,1,3,0.89,0.10
2,2,4,0.45,0.98
2,3,8,0.27,0.05
```

Any suggestions on a way to do this? I confess this is at the limits of my understanding for data handling in Python. I'd got a fair sense of how to do it in SAS, but I'd prefer to keep this a one-language task so that they can be processed as a single script.

Comment: Are there really spaces between the values/headers in your csv file?

Comment: Sorry, that was for legibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ouput.csv:

```
Run, ID, Var
1, 1, 7
1, 2, 9
1, 3, 4
2, 1, 3
2, 2, 4
2, 3, 8
```

data.csv:

```
ID, Var2, Var3
1, 0.89, 0.10
2, 0.45, 0.98
3, 0.27, 0.05
8, 0.4, 0.5
```

**NOTE** that even if we have entries within data.csv, not present in ouput.csv it won't affect the end result, since while we parse output.csv we only lookup the ID's that we know off from output.csv, **though the opposite is not true** data.csv at a minimun must contain all the IDs from output.csv, though this can be easily taken care of if you need to.

code:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint 

data = dict([(row['ID'], row) for row in csv.DictReader(open('data.csv', 'rb'), skipinitialspace = True)])
values = []
for row in csv.DictReader(open('output.csv', 'rb'), skipinitialspace = True):
    values.append(row)
    values[-1].update(data[row['ID']])

>>> pprint(values)
[{'ID': '1', 'Run': '1', 'Var': '7', 'Var2': '0.89', 'Var3': '0.10'},
 {'ID': '2', 'Run': '1', 'Var': '9', 'Var2': '0.45', 'Var3': '0.98'},
 {'ID': '3', 'Run': '1', 'Var': '4', 'Var2': '0.27', 'Var3': '0.05'},
 {'ID': '1', 'Run': '2', 'Var': '3', 'Var2': '0.89', 'Var3': '0.10'},
 {'ID': '2', 'Run': '2', 'Var': '4', 'Var2': '0.45', 'Var3': '0.98'},
 {'ID': '3', 'Run': '2', 'Var': '8', 'Var2': '0.27', 'Var3': '0.05'}]
>>>
```

now to save back into a csv file.

```
fieldnames = ['Run', 'ID', 'Var', 'Var2', 'Var3']
f = open('combined.csv', 'wb')
csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = fieldnames)
csvwriter.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in fieldnames)) # 2.7 has writeheader, which is cleaner
[csvwriter.writerow(row) for row in values]
f.close()


$ cat combined.csv 
Run,ID,Var,Var2,Var3
1,1,7,0.89,0.10
1,2,9,0.45,0.98
1,3,4,0.27,0.05
2,1,3,0.89,0.10
2,2,4,0.45,0.98
2,3,8,0.27,0.05
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: "Output.csv" and "Data.csv" in your preamble are identical - I assume this is in error?

Comment: I also realized there's an added complication I didn't mention - editing that in now. Should your answer still work?

Comment: @EpiGrad `Note: There are some values in the data file that do not appear in the simulation file. I'd like these to be ignored.` this is not an issue, while they aren't being physically ignored they are still entered in the dictionary for lookup, but since their IDs aren't present in the output file they won't be used ... I've update the test files accordingly ...

Answer (score 1):

solution without using `csv` module:

```
with open('data.txt') as f1,open('data1.txt') as f2,open('data3.txt','w') as f3:
    header1=f1.readline().strip().split(',') #header from file 1 i.e Run,ID,Var

    header2=f2.readline().strip().split(',')[1:] #header from file 2 ,i.e Var2, Var3

    dic={x.strip().split(',')[0]:x.strip().split(',')[1:] for x in f2 if x.strip()} #use dict to save data as per ID from file 2

    f3.write(','.join((header1+header2))+'\n') #write the new header(header1+header2) to file 3

    for x in f1: 
        f3.write(x.strip()+','+','.join(dic[x.split(',')[1]])+'\n') #fetch results from dic as per the ID obtained from the current line in data.txt
```

**output:**
`data3.txt` contains

```
Run,ID,Var, Var2, Var3
1,1,7,0.89,0.10
1,2,9,0.45,0.98
1,3,4,0.27,0.05
2,1,3,0.89,0.10
2,2,4,0.45,0.98
2,3,8,0.27,0.05
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy:

```
f = open('one.csv', 'r')
one = f.read()
f.close()

f = open('two.csv', 'r')
two = f.read()
f.close()

one = one.split('\n')[1:-1]
two = two.split('\n')[1:-1]
output = 'Run, ID, Var, Var2, Var3\n'

for o in one:
  for t in two:
    row = t.split(',')
    if o.split(',')[1] == row[0]:
      output += '%s,%s,%s\n' % (o, row[1], row[2])

# or save it to a file
print output
```